# Alert keeps re-triggering

Tags: javascript, popup

I am using the code below but unfortunately this keeps re-triggering as the alert dialog itself is out of focus from the window. I initially wanted to use this a way to capture when user goes away from window including when user is not on window from start (so intent to exit isn't the correct script on this occasion). Is there a way I can place an exception on the below ie if out of focus due to focus on dialog do not trigger

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(window).blur(function() {
    // do something when it loose focus like that:
    alert();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: add console.log :D

Answer (score 0):

Use document.ready to avoid unexpected behaviour.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("window").on('blur',function(){  
        alert("This window has lost its focus.");
    });
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work as needed. What the issue is that I have another trigger which alerts on mousedown when I go to close the dialog this alert is also trigger and keeps re-triggering due to focus not being on window but on dialog

Comment: @Manny :P.  _Anyhow you got solution_

Comment: not really a solution, your changes ensure no alert works at all